# Error using QueryString, SessionVariables and ViewState in SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, viewstate, query-string

I am doing webparts in sharepoint and I want to transfer the data from one to another. I tried the 3 ways but they all fail. Any idea?
It just says 
An unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: ow the query string works in some cases and some cases not !!! it says No item exists at http://*******/BIMS/Shared Documents/EditQuestion.aspx?id=3. It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.

Comment: This isn't very helpful. Can you give complete details about what you've tried? Also search for 'debug sharepoint web part'. You don't have CustomErrors=Off is you are getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transfer information from one web part to another on the same page the look at "Connected web parts" as Greg suggest

If you want to transfer information to web parts on another page the use the query string but don't use names like "id", "listid", "field" which has special meaning to SharePoint like http:/xxx/Shared Documents/EditQuestion.aspx?id=3 which tells SharePoint to load the doc with ID=3 from the Shared Documents and use that as SPContent.Current.Item

Comment: yes man i thx. i changed it to k=3 and it worked!!
but cant i use session variables or view state?

Comment: View state can be used without any problem but only works on the single page and you should use it for a control/web part to remeber things which isn't remembered by the html, to communicate with other web-parts use Connections. Session state works fine in MOSS, but is by default disabled in WSS.

Answer (score 0):

'Unexpected error' == server error 500? if so, turn on custom error reporting in web.config to find out what the problem actually is.

Comment: now the query string works in some cases and some cases not !!!
it says
No item exists at http://*******/BIMS/Shared Documents/EditQuestion.aspx?id=3.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.

Answer (score 0):

Google "connected web parts" - there's a built-in, easy way to pass data across parts.